# Nested vector iteration ignoring outside vector position

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I want to loop through a nested vector, ignoring the object that the outer loop is currently at. Note: this code is just a brief draft of my program, so as not to cause confusion with my current implementation.

```
class A
{
public: 
int no;
}

class B: public A
{
}

class C: public A
{
}

vector<A*> objects;

for(vector<A*>::iterator it1 = objects.begin(); it1 != objects.end(); ++it1)
{
    for(vector<A*>::iterator it2 = objects.begin(); it2 != objects.end(); ++it2)
    {
        if((*it1)->no == (*it2)->no)
        {
            cout << "matched";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "no match";
        }
    }
}
```

So, I want to loop through the inner loop it2, NOT checking the object at it1.

Comment: What do you mean by nested vector?  You just have one vector and a nested loop iterating over each item.  The code in the question should reflect the problem you're actually trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compare the iterators, e.g.:

```
if(it1 != it2)
{
    if((*it1)->no == (*it2)->no)
    {
        cout << "matched";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "no match";
    }
}
```